# Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a trigger in oracle like blow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_VC_PART_LIST
BEFORE INSERT ON VC_PART_LIST FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN
SELECT VC_PART_LIST_SEQ.NEWTVAL INTO :new.SEQ_ID FROM dual;
END;
/
```

anyone can help me?Thx.

Comment: use `show errors`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are few issues in your code.

1) `VC_PART_LIST_SEQ.NEWTVAL` there is nothing called `NEWTVAL` in Oracle. It should be `Nextval`.

2) There is no need for a `SQL` statement.

See demo:

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_VC_PART_LIST
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON VC_PART_LIST
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.SEQ_ID  := VC_PART_LIST_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

**Table:**

```
create  table VC_PART_LIST (SEQ_ID number,
VC_VTC varchar2(20), PART_NO varchar2(20), CONSUME_QTY varchar2(20));
```

**Sequence**

```
create sequence VC_PART_LIST_SEQ start with 1 increment by 1;
```

**Insertion:**

```
INSERT INTO VC_PART_LIST (VC_VTC, PART_NO, CONSUME_QTY)
     VALUES ('6175SMFGD132000D', 'SC25R136', '11');

 Commit;
```

**Selection:**

```
SQL>  select * from VC_PART_LIST;

    SEQ_ID VC_VTC               PART_NO              CONSUME_QTY
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 6175SMFGD132000D     SC25R136             11
```

Answer (score 1):

In sequence to fetch the next value use `NEXTVAL` . Below is the correct syntax

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_VC_PART_LIST
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON VC_PART_LIST
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT VC_PART_LIST_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :new.SEQ_ID FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Comment: Thx.But when I inserte data into table  and another error that trigger 'OTDTEST.TRIGGER_VC_PART_LIST' is invalid and failed comes again,the insert sql is that INSERT INTO VC_PART_LIST ( VC_VTC , PART_NO , CONSUME_QTY ) VALUES ( '6175SMFGD132000D' , 'SC25R136' , '11' );

Comment: Share ur table structure. Consume_qty is a number or varchar2 type column?